# Is it easy for a Boeing 747 pilot to get a second typerating on the 777?

Tags: boeing, boeing-747, boeing-777

Is this easy and responsible? Since the 747 and 777 have a glass cockpit, you would think this would be easy.

Comment: "Easy" is a matter of opinion, and "responsible" is up to each individual. 747's are all cargo-ops now, so the only real reason a 747 pilot would want to add a 777 type rating is if they are moving to a new cargo assignment or they were an airline pilot that doesn't fly 747's anymore.

Comment: @ron beyer 747 is all cargo?  I am booked round trip on a BAW 747 round trip to London later this month.  -Skip Miller

Comment: @SkipMiller You're right... I was thinking that there were no more US operators and excluded my mind from the rest of the world...